# What is a good Geometry computer library? (Language Agnostic)

Tags: geometry, computer-science

I'm trying to perform the following actions with the library:

- determine if two polygons intersect?- scale/re-size a polygon
- minimum distance between the edges of two polygons
- calculate the vertices of a polygon that contains a set of smaller non-rectangular 4-corner polygons, given the vertices of the smaller polygons. (ie. is contained)

The library may not have all the functionality I'm looking for, but the closer, the better.

Comment: A broad term for such software is *computational geometry library*.  Some of the tasks you ask about seem trivial, while others do not seem well-posed, at least given your brief descriptions.  You will perhaps get better results by searching for yourself and reading the documentation on-line.

Comment: Generally software questions are on-topic here only for *software that mathematicians use* closely tied to how a particular problem can be solved.  I'd be interested to learn more about the *context* of your request.

Comment: @hardmath You inspired me to create this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959875/how-can-i-determine-whether-polygons-are-intersecting-on-a-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGAL, full name is The Computational Geometry Algorithms Library,
https://www.cgal.org/

Comment: You are correct that this is a well known computational geometry library, but merely giving a link is not the sort of content we are trying to collect.  Please add to your Answer some particulars.  For example, the OP has narrowed their focus to three tasks.  Point out the library functions that address those task.  Or if you have some personal experience with CGAL, relating you experiences to what the OP seeks can be of lasting interest to Readers.